# Coordinates for the Thomson problem

Tags: electrostatics, potential-energy, point-particles

Is there a resource that lists the coordinates for known solutions to the [Thomson problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomson_problem)? Wikipedia lists the energies, and I'm having trouble solving for $N=78$. The closest I can get is `2662.04721329` while the stated energy is `2662.04647457`. While this is a tiny difference, I can't fully attribute it to rounding.

Comment: Maybe you want to share what are you doing to get this number (?)

Comment: @caverac I'm testing my own energy minimization algorithm, but in all cases I can't find the minima stated. My own algorithm isn't central to the question, as I'd like the resource of the coordinates, so I left it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> - The known smallest energy $E_1=2662.046474566$ which has $T_h$ symmetry.  The Cartesian coordinates are as follows:

```
{ 0.000000,  0.000000,  1.000000},
{ 0.417136,  0.000000,  0.908844},
{-0.417136,  0.000000,  0.908844},
{ 0.223548,  0.364222,  0.904084},
{-0.223548,  0.364222,  0.904084},
{-0.223548, -0.364222,  0.904084},
{ 0.223548, -0.364222,  0.904084},
{ 0.000000,  0.664648,  0.747156},
{ 0.000000, -0.664648,  0.747156},
{ 0.596457,  0.374401,  0.709974},
{-0.596457,  0.374401,  0.709974},
{-0.596457, -0.374401,  0.709974},
{ 0.596457, -0.374401,  0.709974},
{ 0.747156,  0.000000,  0.664648},
{-0.747156,  0.000000,  0.664648},
{ 0.374401,  0.709974,  0.596457},
{-0.374401,  0.709974,  0.596457},
{-0.374401, -0.709974,  0.596457},
{ 0.374401, -0.709974,  0.596457},
{ 0.000000,  0.908844,  0.417136},
{ 0.000000, -0.908844,  0.417136},
{ 0.709974,  0.596457,  0.374401},
{-0.709974,  0.596457,  0.374401},
{-0.709974, -0.596457,  0.374401},
{ 0.709974, -0.596457,  0.374401},
{ 0.904084,  0.223548,  0.364222},
{-0.904084,  0.223548,  0.364222},
{-0.904084, -0.223548,  0.364222},
{ 0.904084, -0.223548,  0.364222},
{ 0.364222,  0.904084,  0.223548},
{-0.364222,  0.904084,  0.223548},
{-0.364222, -0.904084,  0.223548},
{ 0.364222, -0.904084,  0.223548},
{ 1.000000,  0.000000,  0.000000},
{ 0.908844,  0.417136,  0.000000},
{ 0.664648,  0.747156,  0.000000},
{ 0.000000,  1.000000,  0.000000},
{-0.664648,  0.747156,  0.000000},
{-0.908844,  0.417136,  0.000000},
{-1.000000,  0.000000,  0.000000},
{-0.908844, -0.417136,  0.000000},
{-0.664648, -0.747156,  0.000000},
{ 0.000000, -1.000000,  0.000000},
{ 0.664648, -0.747156,  0.000000},
{ 0.908844, -0.417136,  0.000000},
{ 0.364222,  0.904084, -0.223548},
{-0.364222,  0.904084, -0.223548},
{-0.364222, -0.904084, -0.223548},
{ 0.364222, -0.904084, -0.223548},
{ 0.904084,  0.223548, -0.364222},
{-0.904084,  0.223548, -0.364222},
{-0.904084, -0.223548, -0.364222},
{ 0.904084, -0.223548, -0.364222},
{ 0.709974,  0.596457, -0.374401},
{-0.709974,  0.596457, -0.374401},
{-0.709974, -0.596457, -0.374401},
{ 0.709974, -0.596457, -0.374401},
{ 0.000000,  0.908844, -0.417136},
{ 0.000000, -0.908844, -0.417136},
{ 0.374401,  0.709974, -0.596457},
{-0.374401,  0.709974, -0.596457},
{-0.374401, -0.709974, -0.596457},
{ 0.374401, -0.709974, -0.596457},
{ 0.747156,  0.000000, -0.664648},
{-0.747156,  0.000000, -0.664648},
{ 0.596457,  0.374401, -0.709974},
{-0.596457,  0.374401, -0.709974},
{-0.596457, -0.374401, -0.709974},
{ 0.596457, -0.374401, -0.709974},
{ 0.000000,  0.664648, -0.747156},
{ 0.000000, -0.664648, -0.747156},
{ 0.223548,  0.364222, -0.904084},
{-0.223548,  0.364222, -0.904084},
{-0.223548, -0.364222, -0.904084},
{ 0.223548, -0.364222, -0.904084},
{ 0.417136,  0.000000, -0.908844},
{-0.417136,  0.000000, -0.908844},
{ 0.000000,  0.000000, -1.000000}
```

> - Your calculated value should be the second smallest (known) energy $E_2=2662.047213287$ which has $D_3$ symmetry.

Answer (score 0):

From the [The Cambridge Cluster Database](http://www-wales.ch.cam.ac.uk/~wales/CCD/Thomson/table.html), I found a list of the coordinates.

I'm posting this here as a useful link for anyone else who searches for it in the future. I've verified that the energy for $N=78$ is correct.